# Form receives old data from model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have form which should receive it initial value from the latest entry stored in models. However if I edit or delete model data through admin panel, initial data displayed in the form remains the same old one (despite the fact that it is deleted in models). I am baffled what I am doing wrong. At first I thought that its Chrome who saves old data, but it remains the same after resting it with `ctr+shift+r`.

My forms.py:

```
from stv.models import BazineKaina,

class DrgSkaiciuokle(forms.Form):
    bazine_kaina = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, required=True,
                                      label="Įveskite bazinę kainą:",
                                      initial= BazineKaina.objects.latest('data'),
                                      )


    def clean_bazine_kaina(self):
        bazine_kaina = self.cleaned_data['bazine_kaina']
        return bazine_kaina
```

My models.py:

```
class BazineKaina(models.Model):

    bazka = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    data = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.bazka)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bazinė kaina"
        get_latest_by = 'data'
```

Please help me to find out why old data is still received by form?

EDIT: I found out, that if I restart the server data will be refreshed, but that cant be solution in production. How to make form get new data every time its called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **dirkgroten** advice and [this source](https://www.webforefront.com/django/formprocessing.html) I found complete solution:

forms.py:

```
class DrgSkaiciuokle(forms.Form):

    bazine_kaina = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, required=True,
                                      label="Įveskite bazinę kainą:",
                                      help_text="Įprastiniams skaičiavimams naudokite einamųjų metų bazinę kainą",
                                      error_messages={'max_digits': 'Bazinė kaina neturi viršyti 5 skaitmenų.'},
                                      )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_arguments = kwargs.get('initial', None)
        updated_initial = {}
        updated_initial['bazine_kaina'] = BazineKaina.objects.latest('data')
        kwargs.update(initial=updated_initial)
        super(DrgSkaiciuokle, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean_bazine_kaina(self):
        bazine_kaina = self.cleaned_data['bazine_kaina']
        return bazine_kaina
```

Comment: You're not using `initial_arguments` so that line can be removed. Although, I would argue that you should check if `initial_arguments` is set, and only if it's not, set the initial value for `bazine_kaina`. That way your form behaves as expected for somebody using it (if anyone has to use your code later on).

Answer (score 3):

Your `DrgSkaiciuokle` is imported when Django starts and any **class attributes** are instantiated then. So the query to `.latest()` is performed once when you `runserver` or start your Django workers and `initial` will not change anymore.

Set `initial` in the form's `__init__` method so it gets called each time the form is instantiated.

Comment: Im sorry for noobish request, but I am quite new to django and python altogether, could you provide an example code how should I do it correctly?